# Detect last post-grouping tuple

Tags: xquery, xquery-3.0

In XQuery 3.0, how is it possible to detect the **last** post-grouping tuple (defined by [XQuery 3.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by)) produced by the return clause? Is it possible to use something like `position() = last()`? What would be the context for the [`position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-position) function?

For example, say I want to generate CSV output via XQuery. In order to separate lines in the CSV output, I append a new-line after each tuple produced by the `return` clause:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare option saxon:output "omit-xml-declaration=yes";
declare option saxon:output "method=text";

declare variable $data := (
    <items>
        <item>
            <property name="a"/>
            <property name="a"/>
            <property name="b"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <property name="a"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <property name="b"/>
            <property name="c"/>
            <property name="d"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <property name="b"/>
            <property name="c"/>
        </item>
    </items>
);

for $item in $data/item,
    $name in $item/property/@name
group by $name
return (
    text{string-join(($name, string(count($item))), ",")},
    text{"&#10;"}
)
```

However, this leaves an empty line after the last tuple. If I could test for the tuple position, I could avoid appending new-line after the last tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XQuery specs indeed seem to be missing something like `group by $variable at $position` here, similar what would be allowed in the `for` clause. Reading up the [XQuery 3.0 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by) again, I couldn't find anything that would help, either. `position()` and `last()` require a node context, which is not available within loops.

But regarding your underlying problem: why not use another `string-join(...)` to concatenate the items with newlines in-between, similar to like you did for the counts?

```
string-join(
  for $item in $data/item,
      $name in $item/property/@name
  group by $name
  return (
      text{string-join(($name, string(count($item))), ",")}
  ),
  text{"&#10;"}
)
```

Comment: I was also thinking about `string-join`, but I'm concerned about its performance on larger datasets. Will it be significantly slower?

Comment: I'd guess a `string-join` solution would be even _faster_ than constructing lots of text nodes. But anyway, I wouldn't expect this effect is barely observable: grouping requires sorting and is in `O(n*log n)`, while you're creating only a linear number (very likely on a reduced n, as grouping aggregates).